# Check if table exists in database but not in model

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2, ado.net

I am using Entity Data Model framework in my Asp.net MVC project. I need to check if the table exists in Database but not in model. Can any one help me how to check at the controller level for the testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what database you are using but I assume it's SQL Server.

Here's how you get a list of tables:

```
USE YourDBName
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
```

You can use Ado.Net to run the query or you can add the Tables table to your entity data model.

UPDATED

Here are some other ways. You may need to adapt them to your needs.

The [dbo].[sysobjects] contains one row for each object, such as constraint, table, view, stored procedure, function and so on, created within a database.  To determine the type of object, you will query the [xtype] column which contains the object type.  For user tables the [xtype] value is 'U' which stands for user tables.

```
SELECT [Name] FROM [dbo].[sysobjects]
WHERE [xtype] = 'U'
```

The second method is by querying the [Information_Schema].[Tables] system view.  The [Information_Schema].[Tables] system view contains one row for each table in the current database for which the current user has permissions.  This viw is based on the [dbo].[sysobjects] system table.  The [Information_Schema].[Tables] system view will also include views in the list.  To filter out just the user tables, you will only output those records where the [Table_Type] is 'BASE TABLE', as can be seen from the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM [Information_Schema].[Tables]
WHERE [Table_Type] = 'BASE TABLE'
```

The third method of listing the user tables in a database is by using the sp_tables system stored procedure.  The sp_tables system stored procedure returns a list of objects that can appear in a FROM clause.  Since you are only concerned with user tables and not system tables or views, you must set the @table_type parameter to "'TABLE'", as can be seen from the following query:

```
EXEC sp_tables @table_type = "'TABLE'"
```

Comment: hmm.. from the query you mentioned we will get list of all the tables, but, I need to get only the list of tables that are in the database and not in the model.

Comment: I updated the answer for you. Comment again if you need further clarification.

Comment: Can or how to import that table in my views.py